# Android - Loading parameterized query - How to encode properly

Tags: android, sanitization

I'm using an XML file as a database, it gets the entries from a MySQL database. To add a new entry, I have a page that takes a parameterized query for things like name, date, location, etc and enters the data into the database provided the information is given in the proper format.

For example, I want to put en the name, I encode like this:

```
String name = "Mark" // Just for demonstration
String nameEn = URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
```

This is how I do preliminary sanitization. For extra protection, I've tried this after:

```
UrlQuerySanitizer sanitizer = new UrlQuerySanitizer();
sanitizer.setAllowUnregisteredParamaters(true);
sanitizer.parseUrl(url); //Url being the total url with parameters
```

However, sometimes it just doesn't insert the new row. This happens when I use commas or apostrophes, so it has something to do with sanitization I guess.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**EDIT: more specific**

I have a php file that will insert database entries with a parameterized query something like this:
`www.example.com/newentry.php?name=thename&location=thelocation1`

I want to concatenate the url string together with `thename` and `thelocation` (taken as inputs) sanitized so they work in the url. If I use something like a comma or an apostrophe, it fails to insert that entry because, and I'm assuming this, it isn't sanitizing those taken inputs correctly.

Comment: You use an xml file as a database, yet you don't specify what lib you use for that, or did you write the code yourself? In either case, how do you expect someone to answer your question if you don't specify what you're using? And what does UrlQuerySanitizer have to do with a database?

Comment: Well, I use an xml file that reads out of my MySQL database. It's just inserting and retrieving entries from the database, so yes, I just wrote the PHP to do that. The Android side of it does not have anything to do with the database, it just loads urls that result in either inserting  entries or making them all display as XML to grab as a string.

Comment: Your question is tagged "android", but it really is about your php mysql query, of which you don't give us the code. Tag your question "php" and supply the php code, and someone else will help you.

Comment: I figured this out awhile ago with a guy in chat. I was under the impression that it would be best practice to sanitize inputs when I take them in Android and then insert, but I completely overlooked that a simple `mysql_escape_real_string()` would be much easier. Thanks for your input though Christine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look at wrong place for your error.

A url containing `,` or `'` is a valid one so the problem must be on your server side.

I guess you work with the `$_GET["parameter"]` values, so please make sure you do the necessary stuff like `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["parameter"])` before you try to insert these values into your database.

For deeper knowledge search for `SQL Injections`. This might get you paranoid for free, too :)